# Representations of $SL_1(D),$ where $D$ a division algebra over a local field

Tags: rt.representation-theory, division-algebras

Let $k$ be a local field of residue characteristic $p$, and let D be a central
division algebra over $k$ of index $n>2$. How to determine the irreducible complex representations of the group $SL_1(D)$?
Suggest some reference regarding this.

Comment: In addition to [@PaulBroussous](https://mathoverflow.net/a/273819/2383)'s very apposite answer, there is the general answer that all these representations, which are necessarily supercuspidal, will arise (at least for $p > n$) from the construction of [Yu](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2001-14-03/S0894-0347-01-00363-0/home.html) ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1824988)).  It may help to read this in parallel with, say, CMS ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1365530)), which I think gives an approachable introduction to the $\mathrm{GL}_1(D)$ case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An article by Shai Shechter recently appeared on Math ArXiv:

"Characters of the Norm-One Units of Local Division Algebras of Prime Degree"

https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02448

Answer (score 4):

The representation theory of ${\rm SL}_1 (D)$ was the topics of Göran Kirchner's PhD (defended in 2007, under the supervision of E.-W. Zink, Berlin). To my knowledge it has not been published.

https://www.amazon.de/Zur-Darstellungstheorie-von-SL1-D/dp/3868059970

Comment: Thank you @Paul Broussous for your reference. But it's not available.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I received a copy (PhD dissertation) from Kirchner.